# Simple button using css3

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a simple button and design it using CSS3 and preview it in pastebin. I don't know what to add to my code so that it will show the button with the design, because it only shows a simple button.

CSS code:

```
.button {
   border-top: 1px solid #96d1f8;
   background: #65a9d7;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#3e779d), to(#65a9d7));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3e779d, #65a9d7);
   padding: 5px 10px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
   -moz-border-radius: 8px;
   border-radius: 8px;
   -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,1) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.4) 0 1px 0;
   color: white;
   font-size: 14px;
   font-family: Georgia, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
   }
.button:hover {
   border-top-color: #28597a;
   background: #28597a;
   color: #ccc;
   }
.button:active {
   border-top-color: #1b435e;
   background: #1b435e;
   }
```

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `.button` selects elements with `class="button"` Read up a bit on CSS selectors.

Comment: Where is the button with the given class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `.` before `button` in your CSS.

```
.button {
    background: red;
}
```

makes all elements with *class* "button" red, while

```
button {
    background: red;
}
```

makes all button *elements* red.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple link will apply your styles nicely even if you aren't using a form. Also be sure to use `class` in the tag to apply the styles correctly.

```
 <a class="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have specified in the css `.button` is a class.

You need to add that to the button element.

Ofcourse you can add it to any element you want.

As per your code, it should be like

```
<button type="button" class="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are created the button class, but you are not applying it. Just add the button class to the button input. it will work just fine.

```
<button type="button" class="button">Click Me!</button>
```

Here is the the out-put link:

http://jsbin.com/dizej/1/edit?html,css,output